# Manage crash of app by component Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In one view on Angular2 I am calling to multiples components, each one with a different API, that is ok.

I have tried something like this:

```
http.get(`api/path/here`)
.map(res => res.json())
.catch(
    err => {
      // handle errors
    })
.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data)
);
```

This solution will catch the error in the console log but still it going to crash the application, is there any way to crash only the component and not the whole view?

Thanks guys

Comment: What do u mean by crashing ? Point out exact meaning.

Comment: I mean when the API return an error la 500, 400, etc..